# Email::MIME Won't send BCC address in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm using `Email::MIME` for sending mail from Perl script. All mails are going fine. But thing is, when I have given multiple Bcc mail id, For Bcc address Mail is not sending. It doesn't throw any error.
Can Anyone help in this case?

```
use Encode;
use Email::Sender::Simple qw/try_to_sendmail/;
use Email::MIME;
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS;
use Email::Address::XS;

my $mailinfo = shift;
my $username = usename;
my $password = password;
my $from  = fromaddress;
my $to       = to;
my $subject  = subject;
my $body     = body;
my $host = host;
my $port = port;
my $bcc = bcc;
my $email = Email::MIME->create(
header_str => [
     From    => Email::Address::XS->new($display_name,$from),
     To      => $to,
     Subject => Encode::encode('MIME-Header-ISO_2022_JP', $subject),
],
parts => [ @body1 ],
);
$_->encoding_set( 'base64' ) for $email->parts;
try_to_sendmail(
       $email,
       {
        to => [$to,$bcc],
        transport => Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS->new(
        host     => $host,
        port     => $port,
        username => $username,
        password => $password,
        )
      } 
) or do {
print "Error occured while mail send\n";
}
```

Comment: Where is this `try_to_sendmail` function from? It seems to be an undocumented export from Email::Sender::Simple. Your code contains syntax errors, unless `usename`, `password`, ... and `bcc` are constants or function calls. Please show your **real code**. We cannot help you find a problem without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Why do you  build a header manually anyway?

Comment: I do like Email::Stuffer. It's from the same author, and it abstracts away all of this weirdness. Maybe you should give it a try.

Comment: Plagiarised here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1198839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the message `Email::MIME->create` do not add a BCC header.
Any address you send to in `to` that not in the header effectively is a Bcc address.

```
my $email = Email::MIME->create(
header_str => [
From    => Email::Address::XS->new($display_name,$from),
To      => [$to, $bcc]
Subject => Encode::encode('MIME-Header-ISO_2022_JP', $subject),
],
parts => [ @body1 ],
);
```

EDIT: As per your issue with Multiple addresses in Bcc.

You should have it either as:

```
$bcc1 = 'john@doe.com';
$bcc2 = 'sam@ibm.com';
$bcc3 = 'dennis@dell.com';
```

then send it as

```
To      => [$to, $bcc1, $bcc2, $bcc3]
```

Or define a string of Email addresses join them and send like this.

```
@bcc = ('john@doe.com', 'sam@ibm.com', 'dennis@dell.com');
To      => join (',', @bcc),
```

Or you can just define $bcc as a string

```
$bcc = 'john@doe.com, sam@ibm.com, dennis@dell.com';
To      => [$to, $bcc]
```

You need to use the commas and not spaces to separate the email addresses.

Comment: But i'm still facing issue on that. If i add to bcc address into TO filed, i'm getting mail from To recipient. But for me it need to come from bcc recipient

Comment: Because you have Bcc in the Header, you should exclude it

Comment: - I've exculded Bcc in Header part. But still i am facing same issue.

Comment: Now i'm getting mail from Bcc. But if i've given multiple mail id for Bcc, mail is not send.

Comment: How does your multiple addresses get formatted? comma's? Why not just create an array of addresses? Will update my answer as soon as I see how you setup the users.

Comment: That's works fine.  But i have one more doubt on it. if mail id contains apostrophe, Mail is not delivering as well as it's not throwing error. For example, john'dave@doe.com mail id if i given over there it's not delivering. How do i fix that?

Comment: you need to escape it like this. `john\'dave@doe.com`